# How do I prevent a lifetime issue when calling a function that creates a redis connection using redis-rs

Tags: redis, rust

I am currently using redis-rs to set up a simple redis interface, a part of this has me spawning a thread that has a redis subscriber in a loop checking for jobs, a minimal code example is

```rust
pub fn test(
    queue_name: &str,
    redis_url: &str,
) -> Result<std::thread::JoinHandle<()>, redis::RedisError> {
    let event_subscription_handle = event_subscriber(queue_name, redis_url)?;
    Ok(event_subscription_handle)
}

fn event_subscriber(
    queue_name: &str,
    redis_url: &str,
) -> Result<std::thread::JoinHandle<()>, redis::RedisError> {
    let owned_queue_name = queue_name.to_owned();
    let owned_redis_url = redis_url.to_owned();

    let client = redis::Client::open(owned_redis_url)?;
    let mut con = client.get_connection()?;
    let mut pubsub = con.as_pubsub();

    pubsub.subscribe(format!("{}", owned_queue_name))?;

    Ok(std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
        let msg: String = pubsub.get_message().unwrap().get_payload().unwrap();
        println!("{}", msg)
    }))
}
```

On the line with

```rust
let mut pubsub = con.as_pubsub();
```

an error is thown on `con` saying `'con' does not live long enough borrowed value does not live long enough`

I would just like to understand how, in an idiomatic way, should i approach this.

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are creating a connection as a local variable in the function and then trying to use a reference to it in a thread. The thread will need that reference after the function call is finished, but the variable will be dropped at the end of the function call.

I guess the reason that you create the connection outside of thread is so that you can handle the error before the thread is spawned.

What you can do instead, since `redis::Connection` is `Send`, is to move the connection into the thread and then call `as_pubsub()` inside the thread. This way you are not referencing something from outside the thread.

```
fn event_subscriber(
    queue_name: &str,
    redis_url: &str,
) -> Result<std::thread::JoinHandle<()>, redis::RedisError> {
    let owned_queue_name = queue_name.to_owned();
    let mut con = client.get_connection()?;

    Ok(std::thread::spawn(move || loop {
        // this is now ok because using con here moves it into the closure
        let mut pubsub = con.as_pubsub();

        pubsub.subscribe(format!("{}", owned_queue_name)).unwrap();

        let msg: String = pubsub.get_message().unwrap().get_payload().unwrap();
        println!("{}", msg)
    })
}
```

Note that I unwrapped the result of the call to `subscribe`. Better would be to change the result of the function to `Result<JoinHandle<Result<(), RedisError>>, RedisError>` so that you can use the `?` in the thread closure.